# Python - Use values from 1D array as column indices for 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Little tricky to explain it with few words (and google it), so:

I have this 2D np array:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8],[9,10,11],[12,13,14],[15,16,17]])
```

and this 1D np array:

```
y = np.array([0,2,1,0,2,0])
```

what I would like to do is to return the column values from x using y as a (column) index, so it will return something like this:

```
[0, 5, 7, 9, 14, 15]
```

in ugly-code it would be solved like this:

```
for row,col in zip(x,y):
    print(row[col])
```

and in a not-so-ugly code:

```
[row[col] for row,col in zip(x,y)]
```

Is there another way solve this? I would like something like:

```
x[y]
```

or a numpy specific function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use advanced indexing:

```
x[np.arange(6), y]
# array([ 0,  5,  7,  9, 14, 15])
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked perfectly beautiful :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is better to do it with numpy because it is several times faster than doing it with for loop. What I suggest is to slice your array using `np.ix_()` function and take diagonal of the result to get by value from each row:

`np.diag(x[np.ix_(range(0, np.shape(x)[0]), y)])`